# How does React context know I am referencing react-router to redirect me to another URL

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

For my component, I set a context

```
ManageCoursePage.contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
};
```

How does my class method know that I am referencing react router to automatically redirect me to another URL?

```
this.context.router.push('/courses');
```

Here is my component code:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import * as courseActions from '../../actions/courseActions';
import CourseForm from './courseForm';


class ManageCoursePage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        // set up local state
        this.state = {
            errors: {},
            course: Object.assign({}, this.props.course)
        };

        this.updateCourseState = this.updateCourseState.bind(this);
        this.saveCourse = this.saveCourse.bind(this);

    }

    updateCourseState(event) {
        const field = event.target.name;
        let course = this.state.course;
        course[field] = event.target.value;
        return this.setState({
            course: course
        });
    }

    saveCourse(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.actions.saveCourse(this.state.course);
        this.context.router.push('/courses');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <CourseForm
                allAuthors={ this.props.authors }
                onChange={ this.updateCourseState }
                onSave={ this.saveCourse }
                course={ this.state.course }
                errors={ this.state.errors }

            />
        );
    }
}

ManageCoursePage.propTypes = {
    // myProp: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    course: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    authors: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    actions: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

// Pull in the React Router context so router is available on this.context.router
// basically a global variable to make it easy for other components to get data easily
ManageCoursePage.contextTypes = {
    router: PropTypes.object
};

function mapStateToProps(state, ownProps) {
    // empty course
    let course = {
        id: "",
        watchHref: "",
        title: "",
        authorId: "",
        length: "",
        category: ""
    };

    const authorsFormattedForDropDown = state.authors.map(author => {
        return {
            value: author.id,
            text: author.firstName + " " + author.lastName
        };
    });

    return {
        course: course,
        authors: authorsFormattedForDropDown
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators(courseActions, dispatch)
    };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ManageCoursePage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting question. :)

It works because `router` is defined as a `childContext` type in the `react-router` library. `getChildContext` will make this accessible in inside the application if you map `contextTypes` in a component.

This is helpful in many ways to avoid deeply passing the props from a parent component to deep child component.

Refer this in `react-router` library https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/modules/RouterContext.js#L36

And also the documentation https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html

Comment: ahhh i think i get it. So because I am using react-router and it was set as a `contextType` as `router`. I am able to reference it throughout my components?